# How to integrate $\left(1+\ln(x)\right)\sqrt{1+(x\ln(x))^2}$ with Risch algorithm?

Tags: integration, mathematica, computer-algebra-systems

How would you integrate 
$\left(1 + \ln\left(x\right)\right)\,
\sqrt{1 + \left(x\ln\left(x\right)\right)^{2}\,}$
using the Risch algorithm?

I want to know this because Mathematica is using the Risch Algorithm when integrating and can't do this integral even if it can be done by simple substitution. Is it even possible to integrate this using the Risch algorithm?

Comment: Mathematica 10.2 is able to calculate this integral. Btw, are you sure Mathematica uses the Risch algorithm? Do you know if this is discussed in detail somewhere?

Comment: Mathematica uses the Risch Algorithm along with many others (like pattern matching) to calculate Integrals, but I don't know where I read it